# Time between pull requests and merging

Tags: development, github

I have noticed that some pull requests pass tests and receive comments like "works for me" or "fixes issue #xxx" from other developers but are not merged for several weeks afterwards.

Assuming one pull request is not waiting (contingent) on another is there a reason for the delay after a pull request has already been reviewed?

Sometimes I see many PRs merged at once but I cannott tell if the reason was a certain period of time or a certain number of PRs that occurred since the last merge.

Is there a certain number of days (or a certain number of accumulated PRs) that need to pass by before being merged to master?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no hard rules. fluffypony gets on a merge fest from time to time, and will merge any outstanding PR that's had at least a couple days time to be reviewed. There are not many reviewers though, so he will review what isn't, and merge. Some PRs fixing urgent bugs get in quickly, and other more complex ones, or ones attracting review comments, get in more slowly.